# Heroku. What i must type in ProcFile?

Tags: java, heroku, port, bots, procfile

I developed Telegram bot and upload to Heroku. 
But after 30 min my app go to sleep and it can't wake up. 
I think it happend, because i write non-correct commands in ProcFile and after sleep Port have changes.
Here  content PROCFILE:
"web:    build/install/B/bin/B
    -Dserver.port=$PORT "

If it's wrong, what i must write in this file.
Or if it's right why my app can't wake up?

Comment: I fix it. Use web=0 and worker = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it correct -- if your app is running at ALL, that means your `Procfile` is correct.

All a `Procfile` does is tell Heroku what command to run to launch your web server.

The reason your app is falling asleep is that on Heroku (if you're using a free dyno and not a paid one), your app will AUTOMATICALLY 'sleep' after 30 minutes of no requests. Heroku does this to conserve resources for free users.

The way it works, however, is that once your app is asleep, and new incoming HTTP requests to the dyno will 'wake your app up', so it will start running again.

If you want to remove the sleep, you need to pay for the dyno.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer. How i can HTTP requests to the dyno?

Comment: When you create a Heroku app, Heroku gives you a URL for your application. Usually something like `running-forest-5687.herokuapp.com`. If you visit that URL, you are 'making a request' to the dyno.

Comment: It cant help. Recomended heroku cli , but i dont know what is it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question? I didn't recommend the Heroku CLI. If you want to find your app name, you can do it via the Heroku website. Just log into your dashboard, click your app, then click the big 'Open App' button at the top right of the page.